# Why is my Python Twitter bot not using dyno hours on Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku

I have a Python script running as a worker on a free Heroku account.
The bot is very simple. This is the part that posts tweets:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(environ["CONSUMER_KEY"], environ["CONSUMER_SECRET"])
auth.set_access_token(environ["ACCESS_KEY"], environ["ACCESS_SECRET"])

api = tweepy.API(auth)

while True:
    try:
        api.update_status(status=generateSentence())
    except Exception as exc:
        print(exc)

    #tweet every 25 minutes
    time.sleep(60 * 25)
```

The bot works great. It posts a tweet every 25 minutes and it is very accurate. 
The problem is that the script has been up and running for approximately 30 hours and no dyno hours have been consumed. This is the output of `heroku ps -a "app"`:

```
Free dyno hours quota remaining this month: 550h 0m (100%)
Free dyno usage for this app: 0h 0m (0%)
```

Why is this happening? Shouldn't the worker have used up ~30 dyno hours?

Comment: Did you added Procfile to your project?

Comment: with code like `worker: python twitter_bot.py`

Comment: yes, there is a procfile, `worker: python bot.py`

Comment: ok, try with `if __name__ == "__main__":` and they your `while`-loop

Comment: what's the purpose of doing that? the bot clearly works and posts tweets regurarly. I even had an exception and I saw it in Heroku logs.

Comment: sorry I misunderstood the question